# Open GL Es1.0 Texture Parameters?

Tags: android, opengl-es

What do these lines mean, I Googled but could not find understandable answers because they they assume some prior knowldge which I dont have. I have no experience in OpenGL-ES but I have good experience in Android app development:

```
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL10.GL_NEAREST);
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL10.GL_LINEAR);
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL10.GL_REPEAT);
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL10.GL_REPEAT);
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368640(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two lines tell GL what to do with your texture when it is being either shrunk down, or enlarged.

In this case, when the texture is being reduced in size (rendered onto a very small polygon, using less pixels than the texture contains), it will select the nearest pixel from the texture for each screen pixel, with no filtering. This will keep the image sharp, but it might create some visual noise.

The second line says that when the texture is being enlarged (rendered onto a large polygon, with each pixel in the texture being stretched across many screen pixels), the texture should be linearly interpolated. This will blur the pixels in the texture, creating a smooth image, rather than being able to see the individual texture pixels.

The other two lines tell GL that if the texture coordinates go out of the range from 0 to 1, the texture should be repeated. The other common option would be to 'clamp' the texture, such that the edge is stretched out over the area where the tex-coords are out of bounds.

Answer (score 4):

This is rather simple.

First two lines tell GL what to do with texture when it is resized. In your case, texture should use no filtration (GL_NEAREST) when it's downscaled (GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER) and linear filtration (GL_LINEAR) when it's upscaled (GL_TEXTURE_MAX_FILTER). Several other options can be used there, such as trilinear filtration etc.

Latter two lines tell GL what to do if it encounters texture coordinates outside (0..1) range. In your case, this will lead to texture duplication (GL_REPEAT) on X(S) and Y(T) axis, so you will get tiled texture on your primitive if texture coordinates will exceed normal range.